# flutter package - compass calibration

Tags: flutter, calibration

Is there a way in Flutter Dart to calibrate the sensors of a mobile phone?

In my case I need the **compass sensor**. This is because I am developing an app with the help of one of the Flutter compass packages (*flutter_compass* https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_compass) but every day it shows the north pole somewhere different. Only if I calibrate the compass via the in-built calibration tool (Samsung Galaxy S7 edge) the north pole is correct again. Also all the other Flutter packages (*simple_flutter_compass, flutter_sensor_compass, flutter_compass_upgrade*) don't have a calibration option.

However I have seen other compass apps around which are starting with a calibration procedure.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to do that? code snippets. packages. access. further readings?

**EDIT:** if it's not possible in Flutter is there a way to do that seperate from that before somehow?

Comment: Hi Mike, did you find anything for compass calibration ?